# use collection initializer with insert statement

Tags: c#, resharper, collection-initializer

I have the following `method`:

```
public bool InsertUsername(string username)
{
    string SQL = "Insert into [Users](Username, InsertDateTime) Values(@Username, datetime('now'));";
    List<SQLiteParameter> pars = new List<SQLiteParameter>();
    pars.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Username", username));
    return SQLiteUsernameDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery(SQL, pars);
}
```

`ReSharper` is telling me to use the `collection initializer` for the pars `List`.

**Question:** How do I add the SQLiteParameter to the collection initializer?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it when you can. Otherwise your question looks unanswered when in fact it doesn't require an answer anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, found the solution already:

```
public bool InsertUsername(string username)
{
    string SQL = "Insert into [Users](Username, InsertDateTime) Values(@Username, datetime('now'));";
    var pars = new List<SQLiteParameter> {new SQLiteParameter("@Username", username)};
    return SQLiteUsernameDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery(SQL, pars);
}
```

Comment: Aha, was searching for it, found the "idea-lamp" on the left.